# How to create aggregate for count and proportions in python?

Tags: python, aggregate

I need to change the column name to "Count" instead of age_cat. Also, is there a way to do both count and proportion in one single group-by call? My code is below:

```
agecat = voter.groupby('age_cat').aggregate({'age_cat':'count'})
agecat['Proportion'] = round(agecat['age_cat']*100/sum(agecat.age_cat),2)
```

Output:

```
         age_cat  Proportion
age_cat                     
0-10         222        0.05
10-20      14508        3.34
20-30      80457       18.52
30-40      87798       20.21
40-50      72287       16.64
50-60      66279       15.26
60-70      56917       13.10
70-80      33227        7.65
80-90      17463        4.02
90+         5259        1.21
```

Answer (score -1):

```
agecat.rename(columns = {"age_cat" : "count"}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: your command will work but I am trying to reduce the number of commands to execute. I like you do this in the same command,